# ASP.NET Core MVC X.PagedList.Mvc.Common is not installed

Tags: pagination, asp.net-core-mvc, pagedlist

I was using `PagedList` in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Application and now we are migrating to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. So I am migrating `PagedList.MVC` to `X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.`

I installed X.PagedList.Mvc.Core `version 8.4.5`

I the view I added:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
@using X.PagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Common;
```

But `X.PagedList.Mvc.Common` does not exist...

I get an error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace X.PagedList.Mvc are you missing and Assembly reference

I checked and the last version that has `X.PagedList.Mvc.Common` is in version 7.9.

I need to use properties and attributes like `Mvc.Common.PagedListRenderOptions` and `UpdateTargetId`
that are not available in this version...

There is a way to replace it? How can be used with this version?

Thanks

Comment: Is the UpdateTargetId  a property of System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,please provide the  full name ,or some codes related https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxoptions-updatetargetid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PagedListRenderOptions` class is under the namespace  `X.PagedList.Web.Common;`instead of `X.PagedList.Mvc.Common`,there's no  `X.PagedList.Mvc.Common` namespace now